# Как передать экземпляр View в CommandParameter через XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть вот такая команда:

```
public ICommand NavigateCategoryPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand((page) =>
            {
                ViewModelBase? categoryPage = page as ViewModelBase;
                var navigateCommand = new NavigateCategoryPageCommand(categoryPage, _navigationStore);
                navigateCommand.Execute(null);
            });
        }
    }
```

Её задача состоит в смене свойства CurrentViewModel (т.е. в переключении View). Я преследую цель сделать её универсальной, чтобы в xaml все кнопки переключения категорий использовали одну команду вместо 13 и передавали в качестве CommandParameter тот View, к которому должна вести кнопка. Единственное, что осталось непонятным, это передача экземпляра View в CommandParameter в XAML. Реально ли это вообще? Если да, то как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: `CommandParameter="{Binding то_что_нужно}"`

Comment: У вас кстати пересоздается команда каждый раз, когда идет обращение к геттеру. Сделайте ленивую инициализацию с сохранением в приватное `ICommand` поле `=> _navigateCategoryPage ??= new ...`. Либо не ленивую, а обычную `{ get; } = new ...`.

Comment: @aepot, насколько я понимаю, биндинг тут не будет работать, так как мне нужно передавать экземпляр View вообще из другого пространства имён. Как минимум, биндинг ругается на синтаксис "{Binding cvm:ProcessorsPageViewModel". Кроме того, он пытается прочитать экземпляр как свойство.

Comment: Можно еще через тип `CommandParameter="{x:Type cvm:ProcessorsPageViewModel}"`, а в коде `Type vmType = (Type)commandParameter;` и далее по этому типу найти или создать нужный экземпляр.